# Xamarin.Android: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException`

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

Running the current Preview channel of Visual Studio Mac, v8.3 build 1630, my Xamarin.Android app reports a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException`.

The code below works fine in the current Stable channel of Visual Studio for Mac, v8.2.6 (build 28).

Do I need to update something for VS for Mac v8.3?

### Code

```cs
readonly static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

public static async Task<MyModel> GetModelFromApi()
{
    using (var response = await _client.GetAsync("https://my.api.url/endpoint").ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json);
    }
}
```

### Stack Trace

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Path '', line 0, position 0.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Path '', line 0, position 0.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x002b3] in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x0004c] in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent () [0x00000] in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Boolean hasConverter) [0x0004a] in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00054] in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x0002d] in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value) [0x00000] in <12891e825fce44a581e5bbbb579c1d49>:0 
  at JsonParseTextRepro.ApiService.GetPun () [0x0013f] in <a23104cc471e42a78acea59e0c31e721>:0 
  at JsonParseTextRepro.App+DemoPage.OnAppearing () [0x00091] in <a23104cc471e42a78acea59e0c31e721>:0
```

### Environment Info

=== Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 for Mac (Preview) ===

Version 8.3 Preview (8.3 build 1630)
Installation UUID: 6e5142b4-e8be-4d1c-b75e-4744b0d8c3de
GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
Xamarin.Mac 5.16.1.24 (d16-3 / 08809f5b)

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 10.0.0.40 (Visual Studio Enterprise)
Commit: xamarin-android/d16-3/080eaac
Android SDK: /Users/brandonm/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
Supported Android versions:
None installed

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 28.0.2
SDK Build Tools Version: 28.0.3

Build Information:
Mono: mono/mono@6434153
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop@5836f58
LibZipSharp: grendello/LibZipSharp/d16-3@71f4a94
LibZip: nih-at/libzip@b95cf3f
ProGuard: xamarin/proguard@905836d
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite@8212a2d
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools@cb41333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

This is a regression in the Managed Linker where it is incorrectly removing the `Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler` library.

The Xamarin team is aware of the issue and you can track the status of it here:
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3626

### Work Around

To prevent the linker from removing the `AndroidClientHandler` library, you can add it to the `Ignore assembles` option in the `Android Build` settings.

[image]